# Lightweight PHP-supporting webserver: Nginx, Cherokee, or Hiawatha?

Tags: webserver, nginx

I had asked this question on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/265219/lightweight-php-supporting-webserver-nginx-cherokee-or-hiawatha), but nobody answered satisfactorily, so I re-ask here.

I want a lightweight webserver. The requirements are:

- PHP support
- HTTPS support
- Virtual domains (we have some domains that will point to the same IP address)
- Actively developed (to patch security issue etc.)
- Runs on Linux (but no need for binary packages; if I have to compile it from source, so be it)

We don't need URL rewriting ability; SEO has approximately *zero* priority.

Between Nginx, Cherokee, and Hiawatha, can you provide me with the pros/con's of each?

Or can you recommend something better?

Comment: I think you'll get a better answer on ServerFault. There are more active people there. Have you thought about offering a bounty?

Comment: @paulmorriss hmm... didn't think of that... okay, thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hiawatha does what you want](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_servers) and prides itself on security and ease of use. It's been [faster than Nginx](http://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/forum/topic/860) in some cases.
[Cherokee is a little faster but less secure than Hiawatha and Nginx had an issue with phpMyAdmin](http://community.mybb.com/thread-93780.html).